# Where is my error with my join in acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I want to get all the attributes from my "Actual Item Inventry" (From Stock Items Form) so i have:

```
PXResultset<CSAnswers> res = PXSelectJoin<CSAnswers,
InnerJoin<InventoryItem,
        On<CSAnswers.refNoteID, Equal<Current<InventoryItem.noteID>>>
    >
>.Select(new PXGraph());
```

But, this returns me 0 rows.
Where is my error?

UPDATED:
My loop is like this:

```
foreach (PXResult<CSAnswers> record in res)
{
    CSAnswers answers = (CSAnswers)record;
    string refnoteid = answers.RefNoteID.ToString();
    string value = answers.Value;
}
```

... but i can not go inside foreach.

- Sorry for the English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an initialized graph rather than just "new PXGraph()" for the select.  This can be as simple as "this" or "Base" depending on where this code is located.  There are times that it is ok to initialize a new graph instance, but also times that it is not ok.  Not knowing the context of your code sample, let's assume that "this" and "Base" were insufficient, and you need to initialize a new graph.  If you need to work within another graph instance, this is how your code would look.

```
InventoryItemMaint graph = PXGraph<InventoryItemMaint>.CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();
PXResultset<CSAnswers> res = PXSelectJoin<CSAnswers,
    InnerJoin<InventoryItem, On<CSAnswers.refNoteID, Equal<Current<InventoryItem.noteID>>>>>
    .Select(graph);

foreach (PXResult<CSAnswers> record in res)
{
    CSAnswers answers = (CSAnswers)record;
    string refnoteid = answers.RefNoteID.ToString();
    string value = answers.Value;
}
```

However, since you should be initializing graph within a graph or graph extension, you *should* be able to use:

```
.Select(this) // To use the current graph containing this logic
```

or

```
.Select(Base) // To use the base graph that is being extended if in a graph extension
```

Since you are referring to:

```
Current<InventoryItem.noteID>
```

...but are using "new PXGraph()" then there is no "InventoryItem" to be in the current data cache of the generic base object PXGraph.  Hence the need to reference a fully defined graph.

Another syntax for specifying exactly what value you want to pass in is to use a parameter like this:

```
var myNoteIdVariable = ...
InventoryItemMaint graph = PXGraph<InventoryItemMaint>.CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();
PXResultset<CSAnswers> res = PXSelectJoin<CSAnswers,
    InnerJoin<InventoryItem, On<CSAnswers.refNoteID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.noteID>>>>>
    .Select(graph, myNoteIdVariable);

foreach (PXResult<CSAnswers> record in res)
{
    CSAnswers answers = (CSAnswers)record;
    string refnoteid = answers.RefNoteID.ToString();
    string value = answers.Value;
}
```

Notice the "Required" and the extra value in the Select() section.  A quick and easy way to check if you have a value for your parameter is to use PXTrace to write to the Trace that you can check after refreshing the screen and performing whatever action would execute your code:

```
PXTrace.WriteInformation(myNoteIdVariable.ToString());
```

...to see if there is a value in myNoteIdVariable to retrieve a result set.  Place that outside of the foreach block or you will only get a value in the trace when you actually get records... which is not happening in your case.

If you want to get deep into what SQL statements are being generated and executed, look for Request Profiler in the menus and enable SQL logging while you run a test.  Then come back to check the results.  (Remember to disable the SQL logging when done or you can generate a lot of unnecessary data.)

Comment: I have tested your answer...
It works fine :D 
Thanks very much!